# Search: how to extend the existing search to include a custom table

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, customization

I created a custom table 'products' with the following field:title,description,url.The items stored into the table are imported.

I would like to extends the wordpress search to this table.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress searches by keyword. What this means is that when passed the search query "Loren Ipsum", 
WordPress builds the following for the WHERE clause:

```
((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Loren%') OR
(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Loren%')) 
AND
((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Ipsum%') OR
(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Ipsum%'))
```

[This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111436/creating-search-form-for-custom-database-table) answer can be helpful to you ! 
There is also a plugin for this : [Search Everything](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you would like to do it. I am currently building a site with a custom search. I did it in a couple of steps.

- Think about prefered url: www.example.com/search/< product_name >
- Create a wordpress template for your custom search.
- Add a page with the coresponding template. Note the pages id
- Add the needed rewrite tags for it. You will use them later in your search template:

  ```
  add_action('init','custom_rewrite_tags');

  function custom_rewrite_tags() {
      add_rewrite_tag('%var%','([^&]+)');
  }
  ```
- Now you can create your rewrite so the search is a pretty url to your liking

  ```
  add_action('admin_init','action_custom_rewrite_rules');
  function action_custom_rewrite_rules() {
      add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^&]+)/?$','index.php?page_id=<the page id>&var=$matches[1]','top'); 
  }
  ```

  The add rewrite rule specifies the regex to match for the url, and the coresponding query it will send to index.php. The regex captures are remmemberd in the $matches variable, starting from index 1 the first captured group. In this case whatever is www.example.com/search/< here >/ . We assign the matches to your custom rewrite tag.
- Now in your search template you can start a function and it will have access to the rewrite tags. Example, will return your variable. If you don't like pretty url-s you can always search with a get_query:

  ```
  /*
   * Template name: Custom Search Template
   */
  $var = get_query_var('var');
  ```
- And now the query

  ```
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE var = %s",
      $var);
  $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  ```

And in results you have your results, do whatever you want with them.